# XNA No 2D anti-aliasing when using Texture2D.FromStream

Tags: c#, graphics, xna, antialiasing

i have looked around quite a bit and have not found a working solution for rendering 2D textures with anti-aliasing. I have this image;

[image]

when i render it using XNA i get the results on the left. when i render it with Flash, a browser or a graphics proggy i get the results on the right.

[image]

i have searched and the suggestion has always bee to change the settings in the GraphicsDevice but i cannot seem to get this to work. Could anyone give me a working example of anti aliasing (possibly using the image provided).

Thank you so much for your help. I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Are you loading it through the content pipeline? I've never seen this, it seems like it isn't supporting semi-transparent pixels, when it should by default.

Comment: no, i am not loading it through the content pipeline so this appears to be the problem. i cannot load it through the content pipeline because i have hundreds of images. is there anything i can do?

Comment: i use Texture2D.FromStream to load the file

Comment: That would explain it, Texture2D.FromStream does not support transparency very well, give me a few minutes to write something up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When processing hundreds of images from different sources not in your game, you can load them with `Texture2D.FromStream` as you do now. This doesn't handle alpha very well.

I was going to dive into my game's source to look at how I did it when I stumbled upon [this post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/25786/13911) from GameDev.SE which gives some options to solve the issue, and an illustration on what is happening:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBu9Y.jpg]

While option #1 is faster, I would go with [#2](http://pastie.org/3651642), it may look very complex at first but I have tried it and it works very well.

Now if you ever happen to have an issue with antialiasing, or want to enable/disable it, you can do so:
`graphics.PreferMultiSampling = true;`

Comment: ok i went with option 2 (which was pretty easy considering everything was done for me). superb answer! you couldn't have been any more clear or concise. thanks you for your help. i very much appreciate it